# CSOM - How to get video file

Tags: csom

When I upload a video to `Asset Library`, it automatically creates a folder and inside that folder the video is uploaded

I try to access this video by U2U CAML Query Builder but it's not working

[image]

how to get the video like a SharePoint file

Answer (score 1):

Assume `Wildlife_512kb.mp4` file  has been uploaded into `Assets` library titled `Assets`, then the following example demonstrates how to retrieve *file url*:

```
var listTitle = "Assets";
var videoFileName = "Wildlife_512kb.mp4";

var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
ctx.Load(list,l => l.RootFolder);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

var videoSetName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(videoFileName);
var videoFileUrl = list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + videoSetName + "/" + videoFileName;

Console.WriteLine(videoFileUrl);
```

### How are videos organized in Assets library?

According to [Enhanced Video Experience in SharePoint 2013](http://blogs.office.com/2013/03/08/enhanced-video-experience-in-sharepoint-2013/):

> Videos are organized in a manner similar to document sets, which is a
>   group of related documents that can be created in a single step and
>   managed as one entity. To learn more about document sets, see
>   [Introduction to document sets](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-to-document-sets-HA101782466.aspx). SharePoint creates a stub (think
>   of it as a folder) to hold a video and all the related contents, such
>   as user-defined properties, thumbnails, video renditions, and other
>   documents related to the video. When you upload a video file,
>   SharePoint automatically creates this stub for that video. You can
>   imagine the video set to be the encapsulation of everything related to
>   that video.

Suppose `Wildlife_512kb.mp4` file have to be uploaded into Assets library.

Then the following folder structure with content will be generated after file uploading into Assets library 
[image]

The actual video file will be stored under:

```
<ListUrl>/<VideoSet>/<FileName>
```

where `VideoSet` (folder container) name will be set to the file name without extension.